# how to set datacontext of child control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have created user control myControl in myControl I have taken another custom control tutorialControl. I have set DataContxt of tutorialControl to id and I want to access this data context in loaded event of tutorial. but I am getting data context as null. Can some body help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify the question by adding some of your code.

Comment: MyControl.Xaml => <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot><MyTutorialControl DataContext="{Binding ID}"></MyTutorialControl</Grid> ID is the property of MyControl.
MyTutorialControl.xaml.cs
MyTutorialControl_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string id = this.DataContext as string; \\I am getting DataContext as null
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correct but you can send the binding in xaml as a elementbinding

```
"{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=myControl}"
```

With this you can reference the context of another element.

see an example of Elementbinding [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/07/22/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-silverlight-3-%E2%80%93-element-binding/).

hope this is what you were trying to do...